# Getting an error, but don't understand why

Tags: c++

I have a class called Fraction, and I am trying to reduce fractions before printing them on screen.I have a function called redue() that tries to do that, but somehow this is not working. Here's what I have:

```
// Fraction.cpp 
// Implemenation for Fraction header file
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <stdexcept> 
using namespace std;


// Constructor: empty
Fraction:: Fraction(void) {}

// Construcotr: Intializing numerator and denomenator
Fraction:: Fraction( int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("Error: division by zero");
    }

    if(b != 0)
    {
         reduce(a,b);
         setNumo(a);
         setDeno(b);
    }
}

// Overloading operators
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Fraction &fraction)
{
    if( fraction.numo == fraction.deno)
     {   output<<1;
         return output; }

    if (fraction.deno == 1)
    { output <<fraction.numo;
      return output;}

    if((fraction.numo >=0) && (fraction.deno > 0))
    {
         output <<fraction.numo <<"/"<<fraction.deno;
         return output; // prints a/b 
    }

}

// insertion operator overloading
istream &operator>>( istream &input, Fraction &fraction)
{
    int n1,n2;
    input >> n1;
    input >> fraction.ch;
    input >> n2;

    Fraction temp(n1, n2);
    fraction.numo = temp.numo;
    fraction.deno = temp.deno;
    return input;
}

// = operator
const Fraction& Fraction::operator=(const Fraction &f)
{
    numo = f.numo;
    deno = f.deno;
    return *this;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator-(const Fraction &fraction) const {
    Fraction temp;
    int numo1, numo2;
    temp.numo = numo * fraction.deno - fraction.numo * deno;
    temp.deno = deno * fraction.deno;
    Fraction::reduce(temp.numo, temp.deno);
    return temp;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &fraction) const {
    Fraction temp;
    temp.numo = numo * fraction.deno + fraction.numo * deno;
    temp.deno = deno * fraction.deno;
    Fraction::reduce(temp.numo, temp.deno);
    return temp;
}







void Fraction:: setNumo(int a)
{  numo = a; }

void Fraction:: setDeno(int b)
{  deno = b; }


static void Fraction::reduce(int &num1, int &num2)
{
    int gcd;
    gcd = find_gcd(num1, num2);

    if(num2 != 0)
    {
        num1 = num1/gcd;
        num2 = num2/gcd;
    }
}



int Fraction::find_gcd(int num1, int num2) // returns gcd of two numbers
{
    int gcd, remainder;
    remainder = num1 % num2;
    while( remainder !=0)
    {
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = remainder;
        remainder = num1 % num2;
    }
    gcd = num2;
    return gcd;
}
```

Here is the error that I get when I try to compile this file:

```
Fraction.cpp:102:50: error: cannot declare member function ‘static void Fraction::reduce(int&, int&)’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
 static void Fraction::reduce(int &num1, int &num2)
                                                  ^
Fraction.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Fraction::reduce(int&, int&)’:
Fraction.cpp:105:30: error: cannot call member function ‘int Fraction::find_gcd(int, int)’ without object
     gcd = find_gcd(num1, num2);
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is and how I can fix this problem? I really need help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I really need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Fraction::reduce(int &num1, int &num2)
{
    int gcd;
    gcd = find_gcd(num1, num2);   <<<<<<<<<<This is a member function

    if(num2 != 0)
    {
        num1 = num1/gcd;
        num2 = num2/gcd;
    }
}
```

When you declare function as static compiler does not insert this pointer in that function call that means you cannot call any other member function directly inside some static function nor can you use data members of class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your two error messages are pretty clear:

```
Fraction.cpp:102:50: error: cannot declare member function ‘static void Fraction::reduce(int&, int&)’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
 static void Fraction::reduce(int &num1, int &num2)
```

This means you've declared `Fraction::reduce(int, int)` as a member function (presumably in Fraction.h) but now when you're implementing it, you're trying to make it static.  Remove the `static` and this will be fine.

```
Fraction.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Fraction::reduce(int&, int&)’:
Fraction.cpp:105:30: error: cannot call member function ‘int Fraction::find_gcd(int, int)’ without object
     gcd = find_gcd(num1, num2);
```

This flows on from the first error.  `static` member functions in C++ are functions of the *type*, not an *instance of that type*.  You've made `reduce` static but `find_gcd` non-static.  So `reduce` is executing as a class function without a `this` pointer; when it calls `find_gcd`, it doesn't know which instance of `Fraction` to use as the `this` pointer.  Making `reduce` non-static will fix this too.